# Flag declined - answer in comments, simple fix, parties seem to have moved on

Tags: discussion, specific-question

This [poster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22430851/stuck-in-loop-in-python-function) had a problem with his code, which was resolved in a comment string on the code.

> But you used len which returns the length of the list (len stands for length), so you want to check that it's greater than zero, i.e. not empty. And '' is an empty string. An empty list would be [] –  ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ Mar 15 at 23:06

> you are right. Stupid mistakes. Thanks Keysar ! –  vishal Mar 15 at 23:07

> Np, happy coding! –  ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ Mar 15 at 23:07

I found this while looking for unanswered questions and flagged it for closing, since it appears to be a simple mistake and both parties were done, but had the flag declined:

> Problem solved in comments, simple fix, doesn't look like they'll be a proper answer, suggest closing. – schodge Mar 16 at 8:23   declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

Why would this flag be declined? Too soon?  I thought I recall seeing other questions also being closed in cases like this where the problem is a typo / unlikely to benefit others?  Any clarification on proper flagging on cases like this would be appreciated.

Comment: It's closed/on hold now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is you used a custom flag, which is completely unnecessary. If you feel it should be closed for some reason, then use the appropriate *canonical* reason and let the community take care of it. If there's information you need to pass onto other close voters, put it in a comment.

There's really no need to get a moderator involved with this at all. I should have used the "only use flags for posts that require moderator attention" - I'm not sure why I didn't.

Comment: I didn't realize that was the wrong way to flag it.  Poking around more, would the correct way be to select "another reason" followed by "off-topic"?

Comment: @schodge Yes, that will cast a Recommend Closure flag and bump it into the Close Votes queue for the community to review.