# Flag declined: "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it"

Tags: discussion

A couple of my flags have been declined recently

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23584752/consider-the-geometric-progression-qn-1-qn-2p-qn-3p2-qpn-2pn-1 should (IMHO) be on https://math.stackexchange.com/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23533453/how-to-convert-icns-to-png-on-the-fly-with-c-sharp should (again IMHO) be on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Those SE sites aren't in the standard list of "should be on...", hence I found what I thought were the most appropriate sites and flagged as "other".

A bunch of questions arise from the flags being declined, such as "was I wrong to flag them?", "did I suggest the wrong sites", or "should I have used a different reason?"

The comments on [Flag declined - answer in comments, simple fix, parties seem to have moved on](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251089/flag-declined-answer-in-comments-simple-fix-parties-seem-to-have-moved-on) suggest that that one should simply have been flagged as "off topic", so is that the case with mine as well?

The supplementary question is, of course, whether the "should be on..." option should allow for any other SE site rather than just one of a handful, but that's very much secondary to my wanting to know how to flag such things correctly in the immediate future if I happen across similar.

Comment: Migration (or "should be on") should be reserved for high quality questions that just happen to be asked on the wrong site.  A poor question just means another community needs to clean it up.  If it is off-topic on Stack Overflow, just vote to close with the apporpriate off-topic reason.

Comment: I have a similar question, but I don't think the questions I flagged were low-quality: http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/190277 ; I don't necessarily want to argue, but I would like to know how I can get more feedback/guidance

Comment: apparently the link is not accessible to everyone: screenshot at http://www.math.mcmaster.ca/bolker/misc/flags.png

Comment: OK, I think perhaps I understand -- I think related to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253545/new-declined-flag-nag-goes-poorly-with-the-uncertainty-of-declined-flags .  Of the two posts, one turned out to have been cross-posted already, the other was posted to the new site by the OP.  So I **think** that the message is just telling me that the flags were declined, and (incorrectly?) leading me to believe that the moderators disagreed with my decision ... ?  Is it worth posting this as a separate question?

Comment: I had a similar experience: I flagged [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986047) question to be moved to [UNIX&Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), but received a *"declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it"* response, even though it clearly isn't a programming question and explicitly asks about Linux file permissions. If the moderator decided not to migrate the question for some other reason, then the "no evidence to support it" message doesn't make sense - something more appropriate would be preferred in circumstances like this.

Comment: ...and again [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28050223/). Why do moderators seems to be so opposed to moving UNIX & Linux questions to the UNIX & Linux Stack Exchange? I really can't understand this; perhaps this should be the subject of a separate meta post...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Keep in mind that a moderator flag gives you extraordinary powers.  A single action by a single user is enough to get content removed.  It normally takes 8 high-rep SO users to achieve it, 5 to vote to close it, another 3 to get it deleted.

So you'd better be 8 times more sure about it, a pretty high bar.

Especially difficult with request to move questions.  That's been tried and other sites did *not* like to be treated like SO's garbage can.  Understandably.  Both questions you quote belong in such a can.

Keeping the site tidy has been made very, very difficult since the close-reason reform of last year.  It shows, my personalized front page looks a lot like a garbage can these days.  Nothing much anybody can do about it, downvote questions that you think don't belong on the site so you'll at least help avoid other SO users from having to look at it.  They do get auto-deleted after a while.  The two questions have been deleted, your call to arms did have an effect.  Maybe that's another way to go about it...

Comment: If that's the case, it seems like a clearer reason for rejecting the flag is called for, something like, "The post is too low quality to be moved to another site," if I understand your reasoning correctly.

Answer (score 38):

When you cast a flag as "belongs on Math.SE," you're essentially asking for a migration.  Your flag got declined because there's no way we're going to migrate a copy/paste of a homework assignment anywhere.

The second question is an under-specified product recommendation.  It's not on-topic anywhere.  Read the Help Center for Software Recommendations; they have very specific requirements for questions that are asked there.