# Unix/Linux questions in SO vs. Unix/Linux

Tags: discussion, questions

I notice that many Unix/Linux questions appear in SO rather than UL. Should I respond to them equally in either place, or should I be prodding users to use UL? Do we care?  Also this is my first Meta question, so I'd appreciate any feedback.

Comment: If they are *programming-related*, then they are perfectly on-topic for Stack Overflow. But using Unix/Linux is off-topic here, so if you're seeing those questions, please flag them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a question is on-topic on Stack Overflow then don't prod them to go elsewhere; to [quote Shog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/):

> **Be a bit jealous of your site** – don’t blithely turn askers away simply because their question could be asked somewhere else

If the question is off-topic on Stack Overflow but is a *good* question (very important point) and is on-topic on Unix & Linux then flag the question for migration using the "other" option. Explain why you think it is on-topic on Unix & Linux and a moderator may migrate it.

Don't suggest that someone posts elsewhere without first *knowing* that it's on-topic on the other site. This means that you should be an active user on the other site; if you're not an active user then you probably don't know. Even then it's best to just flag instead of commenting as if the question subsequently gets migrated it'll be duplicated on the target site.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254628), any posts I've flagged as better suited to [UNIX & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) (such as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986047) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28050223)) have been declined because “a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it”. I'm really not sure why - this answer seems to suggest that I did the right thing, so I'd appreciate clarification about the reasoning behind these decisions.